# Creating an array of objects from an array of arrays where the key depends on both the data type of array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key-value

I have an array of arrays this.rowDataOfAllGrids which results in multiple arrays with a structure like:

```
[
    [123,"Hello", 3455],
    [456, "Blue Falcon", 53],
    [20, "Yellow Apple", 134]
    .... (this could contain hundreds of arrays)
]
```

In summary, arrays where there's 1 item that's a string and the rest are values.

I'm attempting to create an object using  this.rowDataOfAllGrids where no matter where the string is (in terms of the order of items), it's assigned to key category and the rest are assigned to key series_1, series_2 depending on their order. So something like so based on this.rowDataOfAllGrids above:

```
[{
    series_1: 123,
    category: "Hello"
    series_2: 3455
}
{
    series_1: 456,
    category: "Blue Falcon"
    series_2: 53
}
{
    series_1: 20,
    category: "Yellow Apple"
    series_2: 134
}]
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
    createObjectFromArray() {
      var gridRowDataLength = this.rowDataOfAllGrids.reduce((accumulator, value) => value.length, 0);

      for (var i = 1; i<=gridRowDataLength-1; i++) {
        let valueVariables = "series_" + (i);
        this.arrayOfValuesToUseAsKeys.push(valueVariables);
      }

      // this creates the object where we get the first value, assign it to category and assign the rest to series_# depending on the order.

      this.objectFromArray = this.rowDataOfAllGrids.map(
        ([category, ...rest]) => Object.fromEntries([
          ['category', category],
          ...rest.map((series, i) => ['series_' + (i+1), value])
        ])
      );
    },
```

This works if the arrays have the format ["Yo", 2, 53 3455] where the item that's a string is on the left hand side of all of the other items. However in the example above it does not work.
However, it doesn't work in cases where there's any number in the left hand side of the string because we're taking the first item and assigning it category and the rest series_#.

The order is correct in terms of each item that's a number is assigned series_1, series_2 etc. depending on their order, however I'm not sure how to change this to account for if the string is somewhere else in the array.

My next step would be something like extract the string from the array depending on its data type. Then concatenate it again so that it's at the beginning. Is this a good idea and if no what would be a good process?

Comment: You can't have two `series_1` keys in the same object, is that a typo?

Comment: FYI your `gridRowDataLength` variable is just the length of the last row. Why use a loop for that instead of just `this.rowDataOfAllGrids[this.rowDataOfAllGrids.length-1].length`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the elements of the row, checking the type. If it's a string, assign it to the `category` property, otherwise assign it to the next `series_X` property.

```js
const rowDataOfAllGrids = [
    ["Hello", 123,3455],
    [456, "Blue Falcon", 53],
    [20, 134, "Yellow Apple"]
];

let result = rowDataOfAllGrids.map(row => {
  let obj = {};
  let i = 1;
  row.forEach(el => {
    if (typeof el == "string") {
      obj.category = el;
    } else {
      obj["series_" + i++] = el;
    }
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works really well, further to the question would you happen to know of a way to get an array of all keys that start with series_ ? Previously I had a variable (above) this.arrayOfValuesToUseAsKeys but due to this being written more concisely I'm not sure how to recreate that variable

Comment: Why do you need that? Are you sure you need them to be in separate properties, instead of a single property whose value is an array?

Comment: It's due to a library I'm using to render charts. I need to assign that array to another variable, so specifically I have xKey and yKey. yKey is supposed to be an array of all keys that aren't category

Comment: Then you can do it the same way you're doing it in your code. Just subtract 1 from the length of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  [123,"Hello", 3455],
  ["Blue Falcon", 456, 53],
  [20, 134, "Yellow Apple"]
];

const transform = arr => arr.map((e) => {
  let series = 1;

  return e.reduce((o, ee) => {
    if (typeof ee === 'string') {
      o.category = ee;
    } else {
      o[`series_${series++}`] = ee;
    }
    
    return o;
  }, {});
});

console.log(transform(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const gridData = [
  [123, "Hello", 3455],
  [456, "Blue Falcon", 53],
  [20, "Yellow Apple", 134]
]


const res = gridData.map(item => {
  let count = 1
  let temp = {}
  item.forEach(it => {
    if (typeof it === 'string') {
      temp.category = it
    } else {
      temp[`series_${count++}`] = it
    }
  })

  return temp;
})

console.log(res)
```